# Confusion about ElapsedSeconds.TotalSeconds

Tags: c#, xna

In a Youtube tutorial I am watching about C# XNA, they say to update movement with

```
position.X += movespeed * gameTime.ElapsedSeconds.TotalSeconds
```

This works but I don't understand it. Surely the total elapsed seconds would keep increasing and therefore the entity would move faster and faster as the total elapsed seconds get bigger. What am I misunderstanding here? Why does it stay at a constant speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx):

> [GameTime.ElapsedGameTime Property] is the amount of elapsed game time since the last update.

So this value will reset every update, not continue from zero to however long the game has been running. Your concern would be valid if you were to use the [TotalGameTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.totalgametime.aspx) property instead.